# If Dill file is too large for RAM is there another way it can be loaded

Tags: python, memory, deserialization, pickle, dill

If a dill file is to large to RAM, is it possible to load it in an alternative method. For example python3 is throwing Memory Errors when I load a serialized object of about 1.2 GB.

```
file = open('SerializedData.pkl', 'rb')
data = dill.load(file)
```

This will not pass because the RAM is too small. However, is it possible to load it in a different way so that I extract the data without overloading the RAM?

Comment: Load it into _where_? RAM? See the problem...

Comment: If you have a single large object as your question implies, I don't think you can do much about it. Though you could try increasing the swap size and pray that your script won't start thrashing too much.

Comment: It could also be a bug, either of dill or cPickle like this [one](http://bugs.python.org/issue13555). Addendum for the previous comment: if you're on a Unix like system, you might also need to increase the ulimits.

Comment: Related: [Pickle File too large to load](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26394768/12892)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Dill Memory Error when loading serialized object, how to fix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464356/getting-dill-memory-error-when-loading-serialized-object-how-to-fix)

Comment: I'm the `dill` author.  It depends on what you are trying to load.  If you are serializing data, it might be possible to use compressed or reduced format.  For example, if it's a `numpy.ndarray`, you could use `numpy` serialization.  With `dill`, you have several settings, such as `byref` and `recurse`, which can change the size of what's pickled.  However, if you are looking to pickle data, I'd check if the data object has a preferred serialization method. However, for an already built pickle, you are pretty much screwed, I believe.